# PassBook: send push notication to android device

Tags: android, push-notification, passbook

I already implement passbook to generate pkpass and send push notification to iOS device when updating pass. I have no idea no how to send push notification to android devices. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What app are you using the open the apps on the Android?

Comment: I mean what app are you using to open the pkpass files. Sorry, just noticed this mistake now.

Comment: I am using pass2u. Can we make one code to use with all wallet application in android? Due to, I cannot force my customer to use which application.

Comment: There are several Android Wallet providers and, to the best of my knowledge, they are all updated in slightly different ways. For Pass2U, there is a section called "Updated A Pass" that talks you through how to perform the update - https://www.pass2u.net/documentation

Comment: thank you very much. I will try. Anyway, so I have to do it for every app provider? If yes, I will try to specific application to my customer.